# Efficient way to add points on the map in QML and Qt

Tags: qt, qml

In Qt, I have a thousand nodes which each of them has some millions points and I want to add these huge number of points on the map in QML. To this, I used **MapQuickItem** with **Repeater** as follows:

```
Repeater
{
    id: nodes
    Repeater
    {
        id: nodesPoints
        MapQuickItem
        {
            id: mc
            opacity : 0.7
            smooth: true
            property string color: ""
            property int nodeId: -2
            property int f0: -2
            property int f1: -2
            property int f2: -2
            property int f3: -2
            property int f4: -2
            sourceItem: Rectangle {
                        id:mapMarker
                        color: mc.color
                        width: 10
                        height: 10
                        radius: 5
                        MouseArea{
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                hoverEnabled: true
                                onEntered: {
                                    popup.visible=true
                                }
                                onExited: {
                                    popup.visible=false
                                }
                            }
            }
            Popup {
                id: popup
                width: 130
                height: 160
                modal: true
                opacity: 0.7
                background: Rectangle {
                        radius: 5
                        color: "White"
                        border.color: "Red"
                }
                visible: false
                Text {
                    id: tx
                    text: "Some information"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and by pressing an update button in the map, the following code will be executed:

```
nodes.model=loc.nodesIdsQML.length //This is 1000
for(var i=0;i<loc.nodesIdsQML.length;i++)
{
    var thisNodeCoordinatesLength = loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][5].length //This is about some millions
    nodes.itemAt(i).model=thisNodeCoordinatesLength
    for (var j=0;j<thisNodeCoordinatesLength;j++)
    {
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).nodeId=loc.nodesIdsQML[i]
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).coordinate=loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][5][j]
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).f0=loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][0][j]
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).f1=loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][1][j]
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).f2=loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][2][j]
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).f3=loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][3][j]
        nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).f4=loc.nodesMapInfoQML[loc.nodesIdsQML[i]][4][j]

        myMap.addMapItem(nodes.itemAt(i).itemAt(j))
    }
}
```

**nodesIdsQML** contains the nodes id and **nodesMapInfoQML** contains the nodes points with some information. **myMap** is my **Map** item id. After pressing update button, the **Repater** item is constructed and each elements of that is added to the map. Now I have a huge number of points on the map which by entering the mouse on a point, a little popup is opened at the top of the point and is including some information.

But pressing update button, takes a long time. Is my procedure, is the most efficient way?

Comment: Hi. Out of curiosity, Why are you creating all the MapQuickItems all in the beginning instead of creating just one MapQuickItem and move it around when you detect mouse movement/touch inside the map? (and make it visible/hide when mouse enters/leaves the map area?) . You can use Map's toCoordinate https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#toCoordinate-method method to translate your mouse location to map coordinate to display the info in your MapQuickItem

Comment: What a sense to add thousand * millions points? Looks like looks like a some breach in application logic. shouldn't you add points to the visual area instead?

Comment: @Dinesh thanks, but my problem and the heavy process is not about the mouse procedure or popup form. In other word, I think that change the mouse procedure does not increase the efficiency of the program.

Comment: @folibis thanks, Is there a tutorial which did this?

Comment: I don't know if there is some tutorial but looking at known mapping application I see that points on a map repaint when location/zoomLevel has changed. I would query the DB tacking into account [Map.visibleRegion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#visibleRegion-prop) and [Map.zoomLevel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#zoomLevel-prop) changing and repaint the point.